# How can I rotate my igraph tree (r code) so it goes left to right instead of top to bottom?

Tags: r, igraph

I would like this tree to go left to right instead of top to bottom:

```
library(igraph)
igraph.options(plot.layout= layout.reingold.tilford)
m<-graph(c(1,2,1,3,2,4,2,5))
prob<-c("w=.6", .4, .8, .2)
plot(m,vertex.size=30,edge.arrow.size=0.2, vertex.label.color="black", vertex.label.dist=0 ,edge.label=prob, main="Tree")
```

[image: my tree]

Comment: `lay = layout.reingold.tilford(m) ; plot(m, layout=-lay[, 2:1])` or maybe this is more what you want: `lay[, 2] = -lay[,2] ; plot(m, layout=lay[,2:1])`

Comment: Perfect!!!!! Thank you !!! ... I should have asked sooner... I have been trying to figure this out for several hours.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: @user20650   Please write this up as an answer so that the question does not remain unanswered.